# Adding optional argument (as exponent) to custom math expressions

Tags: math-mode, macros, optional-arguments, custom

I want to define a command `\bigO` where if I type something like `\bigO[3]{\epsilon}` it gives `$\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)$`, and if I leave out the optional argument and have `\bigO{\epsilon}` it defaults to `$\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$`.

Currently, I have something like this: `\newcommand{\bigO}[2][1]{\mathcal{O}(#2^#1)}`, which works if I want the default exponent, i.e. `1`, to appear explicitly. But what if I don't want `1` to appear in the exponent in the default case?

Comment: it should be `^{#1}` not `^#1` (try  `\bigO[10]{\epsilon}`)  then just make the default`[]` not `[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a flag value to represent “no value”.  In this case, since it's for typesetting, it's pretty safe to use an empty default and test for that:

```latex
\newcommand\bigO[2][]%
  {\mathcal{O}(#2\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi)}
$\bigO{\epsilon}$ and $\bigO[3]{\epsilon}$
```

Or you can use `\NewDocumentCommand`, and test if the optional argument was given using `\IfValueT`:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \bigOo { o m }
  {\mathcal{O}(#2\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}})}
$\bigOo{\epsilon}$ and $\bigOo[3]{\epsilon}$
```

Or if you want a more natural syntax, you can use the `e` argument type:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \bigOoh { m e^ }
  {\mathcal{O}(#1\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}})}
$\bigOoh{\epsilon}$ and $\bigOoh{\epsilon}^3$
```

Here's a document with all three versions:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\bigO[2][]%
  {\mathcal{O}(#2\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi)}
$\bigO{\epsilon}$ and $\bigO[3]{\epsilon}$

\NewDocumentCommand \bigOo { o m }
  {\mathcal{O}(#2\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}})}
$\bigOo{\epsilon}$ and $\bigOo[3]{\epsilon}$

\NewDocumentCommand \bigOoh { m e^ }
  {\mathcal{O}(#1\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}})}
$\bigOoh{\epsilon}$ and $\bigOoh{\epsilon}^3$

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: The advantages of `\NewDocumentCommand` over `\newcommand` are obvious in this example and there’s no reason not to prefer it in general.

Comment: Although looking at the input with all of these, I have a hard time seeing the advantage of the optional argument over simply writing `\bigO{\epsilon^3}` which makes it clearer what the intent and output will be at a glance.

Comment: @DonHosek I hardly write any math, but I'd just define `\bigO` as `\mathcal{O}` and write `\bigO(\epsilon^3)`.

Comment: I would do the same.